# Embedding skia control in Qt window

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, skia

I have a complicated custom control written using [skia](https://code.google.com/p/skia/). Is it possible to embedd this control inside a Qt application? How do I integrate with the window events? Is there an example that shows how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may research [qtwinmigrate](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtwinmigrate). But, as I see, skia is cross-platform too.